# How to show sigma instead of inter quartile range with a seaborn violin plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'd like to create Violinplots using Seaborn as shown [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_violinplots.html). These distributions show dotted lines for the median and the +/- interquartile range.

Would it be possible to instead show the +/- 1sigma from the distributions instead?

Their example code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

# Load the example tips dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Draw a nested violinplot and split the violins for easier comparison
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True,
               inner="quart", palette={"Male": "b", "Female": "y"})
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.show()
```

Will produce this:

[image: violinplot]

Comment: there's no built in way, no. but you could turn off the quartile lines by setting `inner=None`, and then use `matplotlib` to manually plot +/- sigma

Comment: yeah I was thinking that, but to manually clip the lines by the distributions would become messy? Also I'd have to write a script to work out my sigmas and I have many distributions...

Comment: kind of makes you appreciate how much is already in seaborn, huh?